# Detail button not saving the url to the related list section of the parent account

Tags: apex, app-development, list-button

I am trying to add a list button to the related list section(custom Object) of Account page and upon save ,it should bring the focus back to the related list section 
Please find image below of the related section from an Account view page.
Relationship is a custom object .
Idea is to add a list button called "Create New Account" from the related list as shown below.
[image]

I have created a list button and added the below as the button url.
/001/e?retURL=/{!Account.Id}&RecordType=012280000001xmx&ent=Account&saveURL=/{!Account.Id}#{!Account.Id}_00N28000009zLC7_target

Upon saving it returns to the parent account page ,instead of the related list section.
Please advise.I would rather want the user to be redirected to the related list section which is (Relationship in this case) instead of the account detail page.[image]

Comment: from the URL in your button code, **saveURL** seems redirecting it to Account page from where it initiated. I don't think you will be able to redirect user to related list section of newly created account.

Comment: The landing page is the Account detail page.The url is https://cs57.my.salesforce.com/0010k000003dBPg?newid=0010k0000058Wmn,where 0010k000003dBPg is the account id and and an arbitrary new id is created which is 0010k0000058Wmn.